# I have an error saying, syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens and many more, you can see for yourself

Tags: java

It says on the line String correctname="Pisay"; syntax error delete this token

```
package StringExple;

import java.util.Scanner; 

public class StringExple{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
        String correctname=”Pisay"; 
        System.out.println(“Enter your username:”); 
        String username = sc.nextLine(); 
        if(username.equals(correctname)){ 
            System.out.println(“Authorized user!!”);
        } else
            System.out.println(“Unauthorized user!!”); 
        if(username.equalsIgnoreCase(correctname)) {
            System.out.println(“Authorized user!!”);
        } else 
            System.out.println(“Unauthorized user!!”);
    } 
}
```

Comment: And from the looks of it you have the wrong kind of quotes around your string. You should use `"` on both sides, not `“` and `”`.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of syntax issue is there, after fixing working.
Say Double Quotes " in print statements are not proper.

It's simple syntax issue if you concentrate then you should be able to fix them by own.

As you are doing 2 tests for both equals() and equalsIgnoreCase(), you may verify using equalsIgnoreCase() only because it will include equals() check also.

```
 package sep2020;
    
    import java.util.Scanner;
    
    public class StringExple {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            String correctname = "Pisay"; // String input
            System.out.println("Enter your username:");
            String username = sc.nextLine();
            if (username.equalsIgnoreCase(correctname)) {
                System.out.println("Authorized user!!");
            } else
                System.out.println("Unauthorized user!!");
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
Enter your username:
test
Unauthorized user!!


Enter your username:
Pisay
Authorized user!!
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me, sorry because im just new to coding and my teacher just forced us to do this without lecturing

Answer (score 0):

The adjusted code is below - the only issue is using `”` opposed to `"`.

Also please format you code for future questions.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class StringExple{
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
        String name = "Pisay"; // String input
        System.out.println("Enter your username:");
        String username = sc.nextLine();
        if(username.equals(correctname)){ 
            System.out.println("Authorized user!!");
        }else System.out.println("Unauthorized user!!"); 
        if(username.equalsIgnoreCase(correctname)) System.out.println("Authorized user!!"); 
        else System.out.println("Unauthorized user!!"); 
    } 
}
```